# PHP/PDO: Mysql insert function

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to create a pdo mysql query function.  This function works just fine if it only takes on array value but if its more than one value, it switches values on the bindParam() part.

```
public function db_qf($table, $fieldvalues, $where)
{//query function
    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (";
    $parameters = "";
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ($fieldvalues as $key => $value)
    {
        $sql .= $key;
        $parameters .= ":" . $key;
        if (++$counter != count($fieldvalues)){$sql .= ", "; $parameters .= ", ";}
    }
    $sql .= ") VALUES (" . $parameters . ") " . $where;
    $this->dbquery = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($fieldvalues as $key => $value)
    {
        $this->dbquery->bindParam(":" . $key, $value);
    }
    $this->dbquery->execute();
}
```

So if i call the function with the following parameters it will switch the values so the date will be inserted for the amount and the amount will be inserted for the date.

```
$this->db_qf("bills", array("date" => "2013-11-24", "amount" => 30), "");
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Try passing the array of `fieldValues` to the execute function instead of binding. You also need to change the keys so that they have the colon as part of the key. The only thing I can think of is that `bindParam` takes the value (second argument) as a reference so on the second loop iteration of the binding loop, `$value` gets overwritten with the `amount` changing the value that was bound to `:date`. This would mean that both values are the same though, not swapped.

Comment: I just tried using bindValue instead of bindParam and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use bindvalue instead of bindparam to lock in the value of the $value variable instead of referencing to it because the $value variable changes value every loop iteration.

Comment: Yes, this works pretty much the same as what I suggested. I just use the `->execute($array)` method in my code so my opinion is biased towards that. I just like that you don't need to loop a second time to bind everything, you can build/pass in the array to execute and it handles it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested and it works:

```
public function insert($table,$columns_and_values) {
            /*
             * Columns Process
             */
            $forms    = [
                    "columns"   => "",
                    "values"    => ""
            ];

            /*
             * Array to execute() method
             */
            $array_to_execute = [];
            foreach($columns_and_values as $key => $val)
            {
                $forms["columns"]   .= "$key,";
                $forms["values"]    .= ":{$key},";


                $array_to_execute[":{$key}"] = $val;
            }
            $forms["columns"] = substr($forms["columns"],0,-1);
            $forms["values"] = substr($forms["values"],0,-1);
            //-----------------End of Columns Process


            $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO $table(%s) VALUES(%s)",$forms['columns'],$forms['values']);
            $stmt = $this->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute($array_to_execute);
}
```

By calling the method:

```
<?php
class Database extends PDO {}

$db = new Database();

$cols = [
     'email'      => 'daison12006013@gmail.com',
     'password'   => '1234567890'
];
$db->insert("account",$cols);
```

Try it!

Comment: Not me who down-voted, but a small suggestion. You don't need to loop over the `$columns_and_values` two times. You can build the `$array_to_execute` array inside the first loop. Also, you have `$this->insert("account",$cols);` which should be `$db->insert(...`.